# web push on mozilla with group ids

Tags: push-notification, mozilla, web-push

Could I send message to Mozilla push service endpoint with group ids, which like Device Group Messaging of FCM ?

```
/*
  some code like :
  "registration_ids": ["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mozilla autopush is a standard push service and **currently the W3C Push API doesn't support groups** or segments.

The only options are:

- manage segments by yourself
- use a service which adds an additional layer of abstraction and supports groups and tag-based routing